# How to write to a text file from a table with Irvine32 for x86?

Tags: assembly, masm32, irvine32

I am trying to take the list of names and grades that is outputted to the console and write them into the text file lab4.txt. I was able to create the file, but I don't know exactly where I should be putting the the table into my file code and how to go about this. I am fairly new to assembly code so some of my methods may be quite unorthodox. Just looking for some guidance on how to get something to print on my text file. Thank you. I apologize if my code comes out weird and not completely in blocks. I don't know what is happening.

```
TITLE  Lab #4 Grade Output Progra                   (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessage1 BYTE "Please enter the students name: ",0dh,0ah,0
myMessage2 BYTE "Please enter ",0
myMessage3 BYTE "'s grade: ",0
InputBufferName BYTE 20 Dup(?)
InputBufferGrade BYTE 20 Dup(?)
NumInTable BYTE 00h
printCounter BYTE 00h
FieldSizeName EQU 26
FieldSizeGrade EQU 3
GradeTable BYTE 20 DUP(FieldSizeGrade DUP(?))
NameTable BYTE 20 DUP(FieldSizeName DUP(" "))
color DW  7, 0

stringLength = 1000
filename BYTE "lab4.txt",0, 0Dh, 0Ah
fileHandle DWORD ?
buffer BYTE stringLength DUP(?)
bytesWritten DWORD ?



.code
main PROC



S1:
    call Clrscr

mov  edx,OFFSET myMessage1
call WriteString                  ; Asks for name

mov edx, OFFSET InputBufferName 
mov ecx, 26      
call ReadString                  ; input name into input buffer


cmp eax, 0
JE E1                            ;checking to see if there is an input and if not jumping to exit


mov esi, OFFSET InputBufferName
mov edi, OFFSET NameTable
mov eax, FieldSizeName
mul NumInTable
add edi,eax
mov ecx, FieldSizeName
rep movsb                        ;moves name into nametable

call Clrscr

A1:
    mov edx, OFFSET myMessage2
    call WriteString
L1: 


lea edx, InputBufferName
call WriteString                 ;prints name in request statement for grade

mov edx, OFFSET myMessage3
call WriteString

mov edx, OFFSET InputBufferGrade 
mov ecx, 2      
call ReadString                  ; Reads grade


cmp InputBufferGrade, "A"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "B"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "C"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "D"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "F"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "a"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "b"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "c"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "d"
JE R1
cmp InputBufferGrade, "f"
JE R1
JMP A1

R1:

mov esi, OFFSET InputBufferGrade
mov edi, OFFSET GradeTable
mov eax, FieldSizeGrade
mul NumInTable
add edi,eax
mov ecx, FieldSizeGrade
rep movsb


inc NumInTable
cmp NumInTable, 20
JL S1


call Clrscr

P1:

mov ax, 7
call SetTextColor

mov dl, 5
mov dh, 3                            ;setting place for name
add dh, printCounter
call Gotoxy



mov edi, OFFSET NameTable
mov eax, FieldSizeName
mul printCounter
add edi,eax  
lea edx, nameTable[eax]
call WriteString

mov dl, 32
mov dh, 3                             ;setting place for letter grade
add dh, printCounter
call Gotoxy

mov ax, color
call SetTextColor                     ;setting color 



mov edi, OFFSET GradeTable
mov eax, FieldSizeGrade
mul printCounter
add edi,eax
mov ebx,eax
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "A"
JE C6
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "B"
JE C6
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "C"
JE C6
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "a"
JE C6
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "b"
JE C6
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "c"
JE C6
mov ax, 7
cmp gradeTable[ebx], "D"
JNE C4
mov ax, 14
call SetTextColor
JMP C6

C4:

cmp gradeTable[ebx], "d"
JNE C5
mov ax, 14
call SetTextColor
JMP C6

C5:

mov ax, 12
call SetTextColor

C6:
mov eax, ebx
lea edx, gradeTable[eax]
call WriteString

inc printCounter
cmp printCounter, 20
JL P1


call crlf

mov eax, 7                           ;resetting color
call SetTextColor



INVOKE CreateFile,
OFFSET filename, GENERIC_WRITE, DO_NOT_SHARE, NULL,
CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0
mov fileHandle, eax

INVOKE WriteFile,
    fileHandle, OFFSET buffer, stringLength,
    ADDR bytesWritten, 0
INVOKE CloseHandle, fileHandle

call waitMsg



JMP S1                               ;jumping to beginning




E1:
exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Have you tried running this under the debugger?  Does it actually hit the CreateFile code?  Does it return an error in eax?

Comment: looks like you store 1000 bytes of memory content from address `buffer` into the file. Verify in debugger this is what happens. For example before `invoke writeFile` open the memory view at `buffer` address, and fill up some bytes with some test values you will recognize (try bytes 65, 66, 67, 13, 10, 0 = should produce string "ABC\r\n" at the beginning of the file), then verify this got actually written into file by stepping over write file and close file instructions (`invoke` is probably some kind of macro, so expect your code to look considerably different from source in the debugger).

Comment: after that also observe how your inputs flow through memory and figure out how you should modify `buffer` content to get the final result you want. (you may also prepare some example output.txt file by hand, with the formatting you want, and check its content in some hexaview editor to see what actual bytes are used to encode such text and formatting, i.e. what you should produce with your code in the `buffer` memory ahead of write).